Changing colour & opacity on a disabled ion-button?
I'm trying to exert some control over my ion-button when disabled.
Here's where I am:
    // Set button colour & Text colour
    ion-button[disabled] {
      --ion-color-base: var(--light-gray) !important;
      --ion-color-contrast: var(--gray) !important;
      --ion-button-disabled-opacity: 1 !important;
      --opacity: 1 !important;
    }

I've figured out the above which allows me to change the colours. Problem is that ionic is still applying an opacity 0.4 to the disabled button, so the colours are all getting washed out...
Is this documented somewhere? I had to try a thousand combinations before I got the color-base bit to work. It's a bit of a time-vacuum.

Just use the "regular" opacity attribute.
// Set button colour & Text colour
ion-button[disabled] {
  --ion-color-base: var(--light-gray) !important;
  --ion-color-contrast: var(--gray) !important;
  opacity: 1;
}

